# Removed new line character appears in write to file but not in print to screen

Tags: python

One very stupid thing happens when I modify a string that contained newline characters within it. 
After modifying the string variable, I print it. It successfully shows that the new line character has been removed.
When I write the string variable to a file, it prints the new line character there.

I spent hours figuring this out!

```
import os
import csv

s = "I want this \n new line removed"
s = s.replace("\n", "")
print(s)   

file = open('my_file.tsv', 'w')
file.write(s)
file.close()
```

The above is a sample code. If you run this code, it will run. The string in my real project is a text dynamically fetched from a mysql database -- which is being modified. That contains one or more \n characters within it.
If in the above code, I try replacing that text obtained from the database in a hardcoded manner and running it, it throws me an error saying "EOL while scanning string lateral"

Can you please help me clean this text into something consumable?

Comment: Have you tried *using* `csv`?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work? I've just tried the code and the generated `my_file.tsv` does not seem to have any newline characters.

Comment: Any chance than in your real code, unlike the code you showed us here, you have `'\r\n'` line endings, so your output file ends up still having `'\r'` characters, and whatever command or text editor you're using the view the file is treating them as newlines?

Comment: So you've shown us some fake code which works, to help us diagnose your actual code that doesn't? How well do you expect that to turn out?

Comment: Removal of '\r\n' worked!! Thanks a lot @abarnert for the suggestion.
The text wasn't visible to me in code form. It was raw text fetched from db. The raw text just looked like a paragraph with multiple newlines. Hence, I wasn't able to provide real text.

Answer (score 0):

Removal of '\r\n' worked!! Thanks a lot @abarnert for the suggestion.

The text wasn't visible to me in code form. It was raw text fetched from db. The raw text just looked like a paragraph with multiple newlines. Hence, I wasn't able to provide real text